# golang os.Create cause "no such file or directory" error

Tags: file, go

Must be something simple, but I cannot seem to figure out. I keep getting "no such file or directory" error. Thought the Create function is to create a new file?

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Create("~/golang-server.log")
    defer f.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    log.SetOutput(f)
}
```

Comment: That usually means the target _directory_ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `~` or environment variable like `$HOME` to specify the file path, they're string literal and means actual path. The error you got is because it treat `~/golang-server.log` as a relative path of current directory, and there's no directory `~` in current directory.

With manually created sub-directory `~`, your code will succeed:

```
 ~/test/ mkdir \~
 ~/test/ go run t.go
 ~/test/ ls \~
golang-server.log
```

So need to pass an `absolute path` or `relative path` to `os.Create`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use  `os.ExpandEnv` to handle the "~" which is only make sense in sh/bash context.

```
os.Create(os.ExpandEnv("$HOME/golang-server.log"))
```

In more complicated cases, you need to **ensure that the base directory exists**, because `os.Create` does not handle it.

And this is the reason why `os.Create("~/golang-server.log")` will fail, because the base directory doesn't exist and `os.Create` wouldn't automatically create it for you. You need do it by yourself like this:

```
func EnsureBaseDir(fpath string) error {
    baseDir := path.Dir(fpath)
    info, err := os.Stat(baseDir)
    if err == nil && info.IsDir() {
       return nil
    }
    return os.MkdirAll(baseDir, 0755)
}
```

NOTE:

- `$HOME` is not always exists, e.g. the program run as a system level `systemd` service.  So you better not use `$HOME` in a production environment.
- the limitation of `os.Create` doesn't only exist in Go. It's caused by the OS kernel and widely exists in other languages/stdlib.